# deleting columns from a range in vba which may have NA

Tags: excel, vba

I have ranges of data which have been downloaded from a third party API. The data comes out in ranges like this where it periodically gets #N/A back from the database. I want to delete the data in columns ABCH (not the entire column) and shift them over to have only DEFG left. How can I do that kind of iteration. When I tried to loop over the cells in the range, as I delete the columns, the index gets mixed up because the range is now shortened. How can I loop over the range given that as I delete the columns, the range size changes. Thanks

Comment: Do you just want to `Clear` the old cell?

Comment: Can you show us a simplified data sample. Just a replica so we can better grasp the problem.

Comment: One way is to reverse your `For/Next` Loop to go backwards, e.g., `For i = 8 to 1 Step -1`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work. Please check that out

```
Range("C18:C25,G18:G25,I18:I25").Select ' select multiple ranges - in your case columns A, B, C H
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Answer (score 0):

So the data table might look something like this
A   B   C   D   E
7   8   9   10  11
NA  NA  4   5   7
9   10  11  12  NA
10  11  12  13  14
11  12  13  14  15

In this example, I'd like to be able to delete columns A,B and E and have columns C&D be where columns A&B were. I ended up doing a workaround but the initial code I tried was something like this

```
  for i =1 to datarange.columns.count  
   for j = 1 to datarange.rows.count  
   if iserror(datarange.cells(j,i)) then  
'   delete column shift cells 
   end if
   next
  next
```

The problem was that as I deleted columns in the range, the column count was dropping. I wasn't iterating over the original range. Anyhow, I managed a simple workaround. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: Ah, so you want to delete columns with NA. Quick fix in your code is not to delete it onset. Instead, get the addres first and use `Union` to set the ranges for deletion utilizing `EntireColumn` property. Ther are a lot of examples you can find here. If you still have question though, I'll try to post a code if time permits.